# Increase mutual information for binary symmetric channel

Tags: pr.probability, it.information-theory

I have a question about increasing mutual information for the binary channel. Assuming there is an independently $K$ dimensional binary source signal denoted by $X=[X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_K]$, a parallel noisy channel $N=[N_1, N_2, \cdots, N_K]$, and a received signal $Z=[Z_1, Z_2, \cdots, Z_K]$. $\Pr\{X_i = 1\} = \alpha_i$, and $\Pr\{N_i = 1\} = \beta_i$. The noise is added on the signal, i.e., $Z_i = X_i + N_i \, \text{(mod 2)}$.

Since the signals in each channel are independent, the mutual information between $X$ and $Z$ can be computed as 
\begin{align}
I(X;Z) &= \sum_{i=1}^K I(X_i;Z_i) \\
       &= \sum_{i=1}^K (H(Z_i)-H(\beta_i)).
\end{align}

Now we want to apply an addition operator on $X$ to increase the mutual information. For example 
\begin{align}
Y_1 &= \sum_{i=1}^K a_{1i} \cdot X_i \\
Y_2 &= \sum_{i=1}^K a_{2i} \cdot X_i \\
Y_j &= \sum_{i=1}^K a_{ji} \cdot X_i,
\end{align}
where $a_{ji} \in \{0,1\}$. The signal $Y$ is transmitted through the noise channel, i.e., $Z_i = Y_i + N_i \, \text{(mod 2)}$.  Thus, we construct a Markov chain $X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z$, and the variables in $Y$ are not independent any more.

My question is how to find an optimal addition operator, i.e., the optimal set $\{a_{ji}\}$, such that the mutual information $I(X;Z)$ can be maximized?

Comment: What is the relationship between $Y_i$ and $Z_k$ for $1\leq i,k\leq K$? Is there a channel there?

Comment: $Z_i = Y_i + N_i$. The signal $Y_i$ is only transmitted through the $i$th channel.

Comment: thanks. Are the sums in the expressions for $Y_j$ modulo 2? or over the integers?

Comment: $a_{ji}$ is a function of $X_i$?

Comment: Yes, all the add operations are modulo 2. So 1+1=0, 0+1=1, 0+0=0.

Comment: $a_{ji}$ is not a function of $X_i$. It can be chosen randomly as 0 or 1.

Comment: Maybe the question should say, find the set of $\{a_{ji}\}$ which maximize the mutual information?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Are you asking this question in the context of polar codes?

Comment: Polar codes seems to be very relevant. I'm reading some papers about the polar codes. Thanks!

Comment: This is much more lucidly stated as follows: $${}$$ We have $N$ sources $X=[X_1,\dots,X_N]^T$ where the $X_n$ are independent and $X_n\sim B(\alpha_n)$. We use a binary linear transformation $B:\{0,1\}^N\to\{0,1\}^K$ to form an input $Y:=BX$. We put $Y$ through $K$ independent binary symmetric channels $P(Z_k|Y_k)$ each with parameter $\beta_k$, to produce an output $Z=[Z_1,\dots,Z_K]^T$. What choice of $B$ maximizes $I(X;Z)?$